# How to set timezone and Display name format from user settings in database

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, timezone, multi-tenant

I am working on a multi-tenant application using Web API 2.0 and MVC 5 + Angular 1 as client-side scripting. In the application each tenant has the option to configure the display name format(**FirstName + LastName or LastName + FirstName**) , DateFormat(**dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy**).

**How can I achieve this?**

1. Do I need to apply to format in web API and send data to the client?
2. Do I need to take care of the client side while rendering the page?
3. Or in My DTO classes, I need to put some logic to convert based on the configuration

Comment: This is a very broad question that can't really be answered well in an unopinionated way, especially without understanding how your APIs are designed.  If it were me, I'd lean towards a client-side solution, but any of the options you gave are indeed possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite broad but I will try to answer. You have a choice to do the formatting for FormatName and FormatDate on a client-side (Angular 1) or in the backend (Web API 2.0). I prefer to do the formatting in the **backend** because:-

- Today, you are consuming the Backend is consumed only by Angular, but I imagine in
  future the same backend can be consumed by mobile apps too.
- The front-end code doesn't need to worry about formatting.
- Prefer to do the heavy lifting in the backend, keep the front-end simple.